# Composition in Python

Tags: python, composition

I have written this class using Composition.

```py
class MyDog:
    def __init__(self, count, foods, breeds):
        self.count = count
        self.foods = foods
        self.breeds = breeds
    
class Eatfood:
    def __init__(self, food):
        self.food = food
    
class Breed:
    def __init__(self, breed_name, origin):
        self.breed_name = breed_name
        self.origin = origin
            
foods = []
foods.append(Eatfood("rice"))
    
breeds = []
breeds.append(Breed("newType", "Mexico"))
    
myDog = MyDog(1, foods, breeds)
```

Is there any other method to initialize foods and breeds inside MyDog class?
Also, how do users of this class know what kind of list this class is expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not entirely sure what you’re asking. But about initialising foods and breeds, you can initialise them in the same way as you are doing now, but inside the `MyDog` class. Instead of passing a food and a breed into the `MyDog` `__init__` class, you could initialise default ones inside it. Then you could have another function inside the `MyDog` class to change it to a new one, if and when you want to.

If you were writing a class that was intended for other people to use, you should also write documentation to go with it, to explain what the class is expecting and what it does. I would recommend looking up Python Docstrings.

Comment: Is it good practice to initialize inside MyDog's init? And what if I don’t have any default then can I initialize with an empty list?

Answer (score -2):

I think you don't need to use Composition in this case.

```
class MyDog:
    def __init__(self, count=None, foods=None, breeds=None):
        """
        Parameters
        ----------
        count : int 
        foods : list , for example: ['rice', 'vegetable']
        breeds : list of dictionary, for example [ {'name': x, 'origin': y},  ]
        """
        self.count = count
        self.__initialize_foods__(foods)
        self.__initialize_breeds__(breeds)

    def __initialize_foods__(self, foods):
        if foods is None:
            self.foods = []
        else:
            self.foods = foods

    def __initialize_breeds__(self, breeds):
        if breeds is None:
            self.breeds = []
        else:
            self.breeds = breeds

    def eat_food(self, food=None):
        self.foods.append(food)
    def eat_foods(self, foods=None):
        self.foods = foods

    def breed(self, breed=None):
        self.breeds.append(breed)
    def breeds(self, breeds=None):
        self.breeds = breeds

type1 = {"name": "new_type", "origin": "mexico"}
type2 = {"name": "hulk", "origin": "usa"}
myDog = MyDog(1, ["rice", "beef"], [type1, type2])
```